# Knex.js with native promises

Tags: javascript, promise, knex.js

My question is rather simple: How can one use Native promises instead of the Bluebird-like promises bundled with knex.js? I scanned the docs for such an option but I found nothing

Comment: knex works fine with async/await. I'm guessing you're using typescript and it complains about the type of Promise. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using native ES6 promises in knext.js is not supported yet. There's a [discussion(open issue)](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1588)  about your request. But for now you have to go with bluebird.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in `Promise` library:

```js
let myPromiseFunc = (bool) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (bool)
      resolve("Its true")
    else
      reject("Its false")
  })
}

myPromiseFunc(false)
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp)
   }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
   })
```

Comment: Uh, I want to use knex.js with promises. They actually have their own promise lib and I want to use the native one. How is this answering my question, shall I ask?

Comment: Misread the question, but if you want an actual answer you should provide code examples and specific problems you've encountered, and what you've done to try and solve them.

Comment: If they are using bluebird in their own library that is what you are stuck with, but why does it matter to you? If one of their methods/functions uses bluebird to return a promise, its *still* a promise, and doesn't matter what promise lib they are using.

Comment: Mostly because I want to use `async`/`await`. I've been told that async/await requires native promises

Comment: @CharalamposFanoulis well then youd have to make a class/module that wraps knex.js and implements async methods. You can't change their api.

Comment: Ugh, fine. Could you edit your question so that I can answer this question

Comment: Isaac what? Of course he can, just make adjustments and send a pull request to it's creator. You can and should contribute and/or propose features, you will learn a lot.

Comment: @Marco well sure, but thats only a solution if the creator accepts the PR. My reasons were based on what the OP could do without the input of anyone else.